# Calculate weighted geometric average in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to calculate a weighted geometric average in R?

I know rogiersbart/rtoolz has an extension to the package Devtools, so you can use the function:

`weighted.geomean(x, w, ...)`

Unfortunately, I cannot use this extension. So is there an other way to calculate a weighted geometric average in R? Maybe manually?

Comment: Searching google for `weighted geometric mean` returns a link to the `desire` package. I'm sure you could find more options if you looked: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/desire/desire.pdf

Comment: `devtools` helps install R development package on GitHub or other sites. You first need to install `devtools` then run `devtools::install_github("rogiersbart/RTOOLZ")`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have tried that but can't get it working. Maybe it is because I don't have desirability functions, but just a normal data.frame with two variables (one I want to calculate the average and the other which I want to use as weigth).

Comment: `prod(x^prop.table(w))`

Answer (score 5):

The [Github](https://github.com/rogiersbart/rtoolz/blob/master/R/weighted.geomean.R) that you refer to has the source code that is used in that function, so you can easily reuse it in your code. For completeness, the author defines `weighted.geomean` as:

```
weighted.geomean <- function(x, w, ...)
{
  return(prod(x^w, ...)^(1/sum(w)))
}
```

An alternative, mathematically equivalent version would be:

```
weighted.geomean <- function(x, w, ...) exp(weighted.mean(log(x), w, ...))
```

Once you've run either of the blocks above, you've now defined a function that calculates the weighted mean. You can use this for example data by running the commands

```
myvariable <- c(1,2,3,4) ##Some data to average
myweight <- c(1,1,1,3)   ##Weights
weighted.geomean(myvariable, myweight)
# [1] 2.696012
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot.